# Python using basicConfig method to log to console and file

Tags: python, file, logging, console, python-logging

I don't know why this code prints to the screen, but not to the file? File "example1.log" is created, but nothing is written there.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    handlers=[logging.FileHandler("example1.log"),
                              logging.StreamHandler()])
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file and to the console')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

I have "bypassed" this problem by creating a logging object, but it keeps bugging me why `basicConfig()` approach failed?

PS. If I change basicConfig call to:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    filename="example2.log",
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    handlers=[logging.StreamHandler()])
```

then all logs are in the file and nothing is displayed in the console.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I can't reproduce it on Python 3.3. The messages are written both to the screen and the `'example2.log'`. On Python <3.3 it creates the file but it is empty.

The code:

```
from logging_tree import printout  # pip install logging_tree
printout()
```

shows that `FileHandler()` is not attached to the root logger on Python <3.3.

The docs for [`logging.basicConfig()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) say that `handlers` argument is added in Python 3.3. The `handlers` argument isn't mentioned in Python 3.2 documentation.

Comment: You're right! However, shouldn't I get exception when using unsupported features? It's a shame to admit how much time I have wasted on this...

Comment: @Jovik: there is probably some logic behind though I don't see it at the moment. You could try to report it at http://bugs.python.org

Comment: @Jovik I think the lack of exception is by design, something unique to the logger library. See [excerpt from 2x doc](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#exceptions-raised-during-logging): "The logging package is designed to swallow exceptions which occur while logging in production. This is so that errors which occur while handling logging events - such as logging misconfiguration, network or other similar errors - do not cause the application using logging to terminate prematurely."

Comment: @wjimenez5271: it is not entirely correct. If you look at the initial patch that fixes [the issue opened by @Jovik](http://bugs.python.org/issue16521) then you see that [it raises ValueError if unknown keyword arguments such as `handlers` on Python 3.2 are given](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/d7660ccd8470). The [current code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/11a920a26f13/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1707) may also raise ValueError (though for other reasons).

Answer (score 75):

Try this working fine(tested in python 2.7) for both **console and file**

```
# set up logging to file
logging.basicConfig(
     filename='log_file_name.log',
     level=logging.INFO, 
     format= '[%(asctime)s] {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
     datefmt='%H:%M:%S'
 )

# set up logging to console
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Answer (score 23):

Another technique using the `basicConfig` is to setup all your handlers in the statement and retrieve them after the fact, as in...

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s %(funcName)s %(message)s',
                    handlers=[logging.FileHandler("my_log.log", mode='w'),
                              logging.StreamHandler()])
stream_handler = [h for h in logging.root.handlers if isinstance(h , logging.StreamHandler)][0]
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

More sensibly though is to construct your stream handler instance outside and configure them as standalone objects that you pass to the handlers list as in...

```
import logging

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s %(funcName)s %(message)s',
                    handlers=[logging.FileHandler("my_log.log", mode='w'),
                              stream_handler])
```

Comment: Great solution since it keeps the code short and straightforward!

Comment: Thanks! The best solution I found to propagate logging configurations without needing to parse a logger object.

Answer (score 11):

In the example below, you can specify the log destination based on its level. For example, the code below lets all logs over the **INFO** level go to the log file, and all above **ERROR** level goes to the console.

```
import logging
logging.root.handlers = []
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO , filename='ex.log')

# set up logging to console
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger("").addHandler(console)

logging.debug('debug')
logging.info('info')
logging.warning('warning')
logging.error('error')
logging.exception('exp')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import logging as log
from datetime import datetime

outfile = "./out/out_" + str(datetime.now()) +".log"
log.basicConfig(
    level=log.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        log.FileHandler(outfile),
        log.StreamHandler()
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

***WOOAH!***

I just spent about 20 minutes being baffled by this.

Eventually I worked out that the `StreamHandler` was outputting to `stderr`, not `stdout` (in a 'Doze DOS screen these have the same font colour!).

This resulted in me being able to run the code perfectly OK and get sensible results, but in a pytest function things going awry. Until I changed from this:

```
out, _ = capsys.readouterr()
assert 'test message check on console' in out, f'out was |{out}|'
```

to this:

```
_, err = capsys.readouterr()
assert 'test message check on console' in err, f'err was |{err}|'
```

NB the constructor of StreamHandler is

```
class logging.StreamHandler(stream=None)
```

and, as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler) say, "If stream is specified, the instance will use it for logging output; otherwise, sys.stderr will be used."

NB it seems that supplying the `level` keyword does not run `setLevel` on the handlers: you'd need to iterate on the resulting handlers and run `setLevel` on each, if it matters to you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `ValueError` if `FileHandler` and `StreamHandler` both are present in `BasicConfig` function

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig

See image below:

[image: 1]