# How to log to file & stdout

Tags: python

I have the following logging set up:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='[%(asctime)s] - %(funcName)s - %(message)s',
                datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S',
                filename='/tmp/affiliate.log',
                filemode='w')
```

How would I convert the following two statements -- which writes to the log file and then prints the output:

```
logging.debug('>>>>> 401 Error: Cannot download file')
print '>>>>> 401 Error: Cannot download file'
```

Into one logging statement that does both?

Comment: Register both a `FileHandler` and `StreamHandler` for your logger. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11327339/1599111) for an example.

Comment: A very simple solution that works in Python 2 as well as 3 is shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23681578/544059).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python using basicConfig method to log to console and file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479295/python-using-basicconfig-method-to-log-to-console-and-file)

Comment: it is not a duplicate. @kartheek posted Python 2 solution to Python 3 question by mistake ([the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13479295/4279) should have had `python-3.x` tag, though it might be too late to add it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it with just `basicConfig` (at least not in Python 2.7; 3.3 added new features, in particular the `handlers` parameter), but it's easy to set up the logger to write to two places. The [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html) explains how to do all kinds of things in full detail.

A few of the cookbook entries aren't fully explained, just demonstrated, but you can always look up the details in the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) docs.

The key thing you're looking for here is to create two handlers — a `FileHandler('/tmp/affiliate.log')`, and a `StreamHandler(sys.stdout)`.

If you want the same format, log level, etc. in both the log file and `stdout`, [one of the early examples in the cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#multiple-handlers-and-formatters) does exactly this, except with `stderr`. If you want different formats for each, [the very next example does that](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations).

So, instead of this:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='[%(asctime)s] - %(funcName)s - %(message)s',
                datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S',
                filename='/tmp/affiliate.log',
                filemode='w')
```

Do this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler('/tmp/affiliate.log')
sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] - %(funcName)s - %(message)s',
                               datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
sh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(sh)
```

Note that the second example I linked uses `basicConfig` to do everything it can do, then adds a second handler on top of it. I think this is a little less clear, but if you want to do the same, you can do it.

Comment: You can do it with just `basicConfig()` in Python 3.3+ via `handlers` parameter.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Good point. The OP is clearly using 2.x, but for future searchers that's worth mentioning.