# Python logging basicConfig to file and bash

Tags: python, logging

How can I set up the basic logging to write to a logfile and also print output to terminal?

I use basicConfig to set up logging for modules and sub modules.

Problem:
If I use logging.basicConfig(filename=LOGFILE, …) there is no more terminal output from logging module.
If I add another FileHandler for the logfile, this is only used by main module and not by sub modules, example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format="%(name)s (%(lineno)s): %(message)s",
        filename=LOGFILE
        )
    # add logfile   
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(name)s (%(lineno)s): %(message)s")
    logfile = logging.FileHandler(LOGFILE)
    logfile.setLevel("DEBUG")
    logfile.setFormatter(formatter)
```

Using Python 2.7

### Update

Just found https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733863/1907997 but example is not working, no output on terminal or file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logFormatter = "%(name)s (%(lineno)s): %(message)s"
    rootLogger = logging.getLogger()

    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(LOGFILE)
    fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
    fileHandler.setLevel("DEBUG")

    rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)

    consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
    consoleHandler.setLevel("DEBUG")

    rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
```

#### Info for newer Python Version:

.
Since Python 3.3 logging.basicConfig() can take a keyword argument handlers
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46098711/1907997

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s (%(lineno)s) - %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
    datefmt='%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S', 
    filename=LOGFILE
    )

rootLogger = logging.getLogger("")
logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s (%(lineno)s) - %(levelname)s: %(message)s")
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
consoleHandler.setLevel("DEBUG")
rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
```

found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23681578/1907997