# Does the logging module have an in-built function for datetime / calling-from-program as part of the log filename?

Tags: python, datetime, logging

When I run a program someprogram.py, I would prefer a log filename like:

```
someprogram.py_2021_11_10_20_25_00.log
```

So that the name of the logfile tells me from which program it is generated and what time that program started.

This is not difficult to implement.

But since we're using a logging module, I would expect this to be built-in in logging.basicConfig, so something like:
`logging.basicConfig(filename=module_%(asctime)s,`

Comment: asking for coding on command is not permitted at SO. Show more effort on what you've tried. End of Review.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a name as a keyword like in the example here in [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html)

**Here your Module / file**
The 'filename' 'spam_application.auxiliary'

```
import logging
import sys
# create logger
MODULE_NAME = 'spam_application.auxiliary' # Keyword of the file / Module
module_logger = logging.getLogger(MODULE_NAME)

class Auxiliary:
    class_name = 'spam_application.auxiliary.Auxiliary' # Class name
    def __init__(self):
        module_logger.info('creating an instance of Auxiliary')
        self.logger = self.set_up_config()
        self.logger.info('instance of Auxiliary initialized!')
    def do_something(self):
        self.logger.info('doing something')
        a = 1 + 1
        self.logger.info('done doing something')

    def set_up_config(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger(self.class_name)
        format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s ' # Set up the asctime
        FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(format)
        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)  # Using sys.stdout
        stream_handler.terminator = '\n=====================================================\n'
        stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        stream_handler.setFormatter(FORMATTER)
        logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
        return logger

def some_function():
    module_logger.info('received a call to "some_function"')
```

### Parent module / Child as per documentation

```
import logging
import auxiliary_module

# create logger with 'spam_application'
logger = logging.getLogger('spam_application')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)

logger.info('creating an instance of auxiliary_module.Auxiliary')
a = auxiliary_module.Auxiliary()
logger.info('created an instance of auxiliary_module.Auxiliary')
logger.info('calling auxiliary_module.Auxiliary.do_something')
a.do_something()
logger.info('finished auxiliary_module.Auxiliary.do_something')
logger.info('calling auxiliary_module.some_function()')
auxiliary_module.some_function()
logger.info('done with auxiliary_module.some_function()')
```

**## Calling the logger from another module ##**

```
import logging
import auxiliary_module

a = auxiliary_module.Auxiliary()
aux_module = logging.getLogger('spam_application.auxiliary.Auxiliary')
aux_module.setLevel(logging.INFO)
aux_module.info("Hey")

# 2021-11-10 21:18:04,376 INFO spam_application.auxiliary.Auxiliary: Hey 
# =====================================================
```

---

### Most simple way to config logger

```
import logging

format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s '
logging.basicConfig(
     level=logging.INFO,
     format= format,
     datefmt='%H:%M:%S'
 )
_logger = logging.getLogger('MY_MODULE_NAME')
_logger.info("Here a log")
```

**Output**

```
>>> 20:55:12 INFO __main__: Hello WOrld
```

### Using StreamerHandler

Needed to register a different logger

```
import logging
import sys

_logger = logging.getLogger('MY_MODULE_NAME')
_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# Streamer Registartion
format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s '
FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(format)
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout) # Using sys.stdout
stream_handler.terminator = '\n====================================================='
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
stream_handler.setFormatter(FORMATTER)
_logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

_logger.info("Here a log")
```

### Same but with a separate streamar

Useful to retrieve some other logs later on. same method can be used to write to a log file

```
import logging
import sys
import io

_logger = logging.getLogger('MY_MODULE_NAME')
_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# Streamer Registartion
format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s '
FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(format)
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout) # Using sys.stdout
stream_handler.terminator = '\n====================================================='
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
stream_handler.setFormatter(FORMATTER)
_logger.addHandler(stream_handler)


# Add to a streamer
streamer = io.StringIO()
format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s '
FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(format)
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=streamer) # We use stringio
stream_handler.terminator = '\n*******************************************************'
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
stream_handler.setFormatter(FORMATTER)
_logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

_logger.info("Here a log")

# Get All logged valued from streamer

steramed_values = streamer.getvalue()
print(f'steramed_values --> \n{steramed_values}')


# 2021-11-10 21:02:15,492 INFO __main__: Here a log 
# =====================================================steramed_values --> 
# 2021-11-10 21:02:15,492 INFO __main__: Here a log 
# *******************************************************
```

### Related Topic / Documentation

- [Loggin CookBook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html)
- [BasicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)
- [Python using basicConfig method to log to console and file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479295/python-using-basicconfig-method-to-log-to-console-and-file)
- [Making Python loggers output all messages to stdout in addition to log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058453/making-python-loggers-output-all-messages-to-stdout-in-addition-to-log-file)